# How can I throw TypeError with message inside if statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, exception

### What I want to do

I would like to fix my current code to pass the coding challenge, [Codewars Prefill an Array](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54129112fb7c188740000162/train/python).

I hope to learn how to throw TypeError with message with `if` statement in this case.

> Create the function prefill that returns an array of n elements thatall have the same value v. See if you can do this without using a loop.
>
> You have to validate input: v can be anything (primitive orotherwise) if v is ommited, fill the array with undefined if n is 0, return an empty array if n is anything other than an integer or integer-formatted string (e.g. '123') that is >=0, throw a TypeError
>
> When throwing a TypeError, the message should be n is invalid, where
>   you replace n for the actual value passed to the function.

```
Code Examples
    prefill(3,1) --> [1,1,1]

    prefill(2,"abc") --> ['abc','abc']

    prefill("1", 1) --> [1]

    prefill(3, prefill(2,'2d'))
      --> [['2d','2d'],['2d','2d'],['2d','2d']]

    prefill("xyz", 1)
      --> throws TypeError with message "xyz is invalid"
```

### Problem

I have passed 4 sample tests among 5 sample tests, but I cannot pass the below one.

```
    prefill("xyz", 1)
      --> throws TypeError with message "xyz is invalid"
```

### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 8,
in <module> prefill('xyz', 1) File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", 
line 3, in prefill if int(n): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xyz'
```

### Current code

```py
def prefill(n,v):

    if int(n):
        result = [0] * int(n)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            result[i] = v
        return result

    else:
        return TypeError, str(n) + "is invalid"
```

### Developing Environment

Python 3.4.3

Comment: Please clarify your problem. All Exceptions are thrown using ``raise``, and caught using ``try: except:``. ``TypeError`` and ``ValueError`` are no different in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try`-`except` to catch the error, and throw for example another one:

```
def prefill(n,v):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(n))
    else:
        return [v] * n
```

For example:

```
>>> prefill(3,1)
[1, 1, 1]
>>> prefill(2,"abc")
['abc', 'abc']
>>> prefill("1", 1)
[1]
>>> prefill(3, prefill(2,'2d'))
[['2d', '2d'], ['2d', '2d'], ['2d', '2d']]
>>> prefill("xyz", 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in prefill
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xyz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in prefill
TypeError: xyz is invalid
```

You do not per se need to specify an exception to `raise`. In case you want to *re*-raise the exception, simply writing `raise` is sufficient. You can furthermore specify a tuple of exceptions to catch, and make `v` optional here, for example:

```
def prefill(n,v=None):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(n))
    else:
        return [v] * n
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `raise` keyword to raise an exception, rather than return it. `raise` is used to generate a new exception:

```
>>> raise TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError
```

In this example I raised the `TypeError` by using the exception class directly. You can also create instances of the error like this:

```
>>> t=TypeError()
>>> raise t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError
```

Doing it that way allows various properties to be set on the object before using `raise`. The problem posted includes this requirement:

> When throwing a TypeError, the message should be n is invalid, where you replace n for the actual value passed to the function.

That is an example of a situation where it is necessary to create an instance of the error and set a message property on it before using `raise`. That can still be done in one line:

```
>>> raise TypeError("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo
```

To *catch* exceptions, use a `try-except` block, rather than an `if` block:

```
x = 'hello, world!'
try:
    y = x / 2
except TypeError as e:
    e.args = (*e.args, str(x) + " is not valid")
    raise
```

This will raise an error:

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'", 'hello, world! is not valid')
```

---

note that you can check the datatype of a variable using `type()`:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> if type(x) == int:
...   print("it's an int")
...
it's an int
```

Also, the code sample could be simplified to:

```
    return [v for _ in range(n)]
```